# Virtual host and htaccess issues and too many redirect in yii project setup

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

This project is on yii 1.1. I setup the project under htdocs folder. It redirects too many times. I also setup a virtual host for it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/message_board"
ServerName message_board.dev
ServerAlias www.message_board.dev
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/message_board">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here is the `.htaccess` code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request is not for the /sts/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sts/ [NC]
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make below changes.

Changes into virtual host file:

```
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/message_board">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

.htaccess changes:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```